# Why this Selection sort code in Cpp, not giving required Output

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int min_arr(int arr[],int size);
void swap(int *,int *);
int main()
{
    int arr[10]={31,2,55,3,77,12,89,98,43,34},loc;
    int* arr1;
    arr1 = &arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for( int j=i;j<9;j++)
        {
            loc = min_arr(arr1,(10-i));
            swap(&arr[loc],&arr[i]);
            arr1++;
        }
    }   

    for(int i =0; i<10;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int min_arr(int arr[],int size)
{
    int k=0;
    int temp=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]<temp)
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            k=i;
        }   
    }

    return k;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int temp;
   temp=*a;
   *a=*b;
   *b=temp;
}
```

Why this Selection sort code in Cpp, not giving required Output? Kindly find the flaw! I have taken two functions to find min of the sub arrays as we procede. And as i find the min, i return its index and swap the first position of the sub array and minimum valued element!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rearranging the code and adding some debug lines, it's pretty easy to find out what's wrong:

- Firstly, the second loop (j loop) is completely pointless
- Secondly loc variable is not 0-based but i-based (as you searched over arr1, which is incremented by the loop), so arr[loc] should be arr[loc+i]

Corrected, smartly indented (that's important to make tour code easily readable) code:

```
#include<iostream>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
using namespace std;
int min_arr(int arr[],int size);
void swap(int *,int *);
int main()
{
    int arr[ARRAY_SIZE]={31,2,55,3,77,12,89,98,43,34},loc;
    int* arr1;
    arr1 = &arr[0];
    for( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ )
    {
        //for( int j = i; j<ARRAY_SIZE-1; j++ )
        {
            loc = min_arr(arr1,(ARRAY_SIZE-i));
            // for debug:
            //std::cout << "min found at " << loc << std::endl;
            swap(&arr[loc+i],&arr[i]);

            // for debug:
            //for( int i =0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++ )
            //  cout << arr[i] << " ";
            //cout << std::endl;

            arr1++;
        }
    }   

    for( int i =0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++ )
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int min_arr( int arr[], int size )
{
    int k=0;
    int temp=arr[0];
    for( int i=1; i<size; i++ )
    {
        if( arr[i] < temp )
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            k=i;
        }   
    }
    return k;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
```

It will output:

```
2
3
12
31
34
43
55
77
89
98
```

Comment: I coundnt get what you said about loc. Why it was made loc+i ?

Comment: loc is the position of the minimum value in arr1. But, as arr1 is incremented by your loop arr1[loc] is actually arr[loc+i] (because arr1 is actually arr+i).

Answer (score 0):

In your version you just go with pointers beyond the area mapped for the array.

First of all, call of the function min_arr. It requires array, not pointer:

```
loc=min_arr(arr,(10-i));
```

Second, the function itself. You always start from the beginning of the array, that's why already sorted elements go resorted.

```
int min_arr(int arr[],int size)
{
int k=10-size;
int temp=arr[k];
for(int i=k+1;i<10;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]<temp)
    {
        temp=arr[i];
        k=i;
    }
    }

   return k;
}
```

Comment: I didnt get the point.
First:- The function min_arr() is already taking array argument.
Secondly, my function starts from the beginning because i am parsing array 'arr1' and not 'arr' !

What you said will, I guess, eliminate the need of 'arr1' ?

Comment: Yes, there is no more need in arr1. I assume, you want the function to work with subarray, passing to it a pointer to the according element, but there are couple of problems:
1) arr1 goes beyond the area mapped for the array, because it was introduced in the inner loop
2) you try to work with subarray indices  within the function min_arr, however you then transfer &arr[loc] (so loc now is an index in original array) to swap
That's why I suggest to pass to min_arr original array and index of the element, from which you want start to look for a min

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    for( int j=i;j<9;j++)  //shouldn't this be j < 10 ?
......
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but you should test your code before proposing any answer...Actually, this j loop is pointless and your proposal does not make the code work...